# MFC's CRuntimeClass replacement in D

Tags: c++, mfc, d

StackOverflow. My first post here.
I've come to D from C++ and MFC, which i'm using in my job - not only GUI stuff, but many MFC's macro(`DECLARE_DYNCREATE`, etc.) and `CObject` class.
How i saw, in D we have `std.Object` class with `factory` method.

So, how to *correctly* rewrite this C++ code in D? if it is possible, of course.

```
class CPerson : public CObject 
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC( CPerson )
    // other declarations
};
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC( CPerson, CObject )
void DoSmthWithObject(const CObject* pObj)
{
    CPerson* pPerson = dynamic_cast<CPerson*>(pObj);
    ASSERT_VALID(pPerson);
    // Work with out CPerson object.
}

// Somethere in code create our CObject...
CObject* pMyObject = new CPerson;

// .. and do some strange things with it.
DoSmthWithObject(pMyObject);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downcasts are already runtime-checked in D. Attempting to perform an invalid downcast will result in a null reference.

```
class A { }
class B : A { }
class C { }

unittest
{
    A a = new A();
    Object o = a;               // upcasts are implicit
    assert(o !is null);         // OK, all classes implicitly descend from Object
    assert(cast(A)o !is null);  // OK, same class
    assert(cast(B)o is null);   // Not allowed, B is subclass of A
    assert(cast(B)a is null);   // Ditto
    assert(cast(C)o is null);   // Not allowed, C is unrelated to A
    assert(cast(C)a is null);   // Ditto
    assert(cast(C)cast(void*)a !is null); // Use intermediate cast to
                                          // void* to bypass runtime checks
}
```

Comment: Offtop: you are author of ae library? interesting project, i check some it code.  About the subj: how to determine _real_ type of `a` at runtime?  for example, in function like `void DoSmth(A a)`.  `typeof` use compile-time information about type, so it always show `A`.  And thanks for answer.

Comment: Aha. So, thanks again and good luck with your D projects - they are impressive. And the last question: D already have compile-time reflection. But how about runtime one, like Qt QMetaObject stuff?

Comment: @Trass3r Ok, now it's clear. But, where i can get more information about this? How i understand, traits + mixins already allow to add some field/member functions information(`Variant[string] fields`) to any D class in compile-time - and retrieve it in run-time.